# Active Directory: Find out which users belong to a Group Policy Object

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I want to make sure that certain users are available in a group from the windows domain. I installed "Group Policy Management" and can open the Forest, the Domain. But then I am not sure what I am searching. I can select a link to a Group Policy Object (GPO). In Settings i see the Drive Maps and I know them. But how can I display a list of users that use this GPO? Right-click, Edit... is disabled.

net group my_gpo

does not work since I am not on a Windows Domain Controller. Any possibility to find out anyway?

Answer (score 2):

*Group Policies* and *groups* are two completely different things.
And yes, I know the names are misleading.

A Group Policy Object is a set of policies linked to one or more Organizational Units in Active Directory; they will affect all computer and/or users in that container and below (there are exceptions, but this is the core concept).

A group is, just like the name implies, a collection of users, computers or other groups; it can be located anywhere in AD, and its members also can be located anywhere. It's mainly used for security, because assigning permissions to a group is a lot easier than doing the same for each individual user (but it can also act as a mail distribution list where Exchange is in use).

To manage Groups Policies, you use the `Group Policy Management Console`.

To manage groups (or users, or computers, or Active Directory in general) you use `Active Directory Users and Computers`.

If you need to check who is member of a given group, ADUC is the right tool to use; GPMC will not tell you anything about that, because it's not its job.

ADUC is always present on Domain Controllers, and can be installed on Windows Server systems as a feature (part of AD DS Tools).

If you want to use it on a client system, you'll need to install [Remote Server Administration Tools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/system-management-components/remote-server-administration-tools).

---

Addendum: the `net group` command applies to *groups*, which as I said above are different from GPOs. It doesn't make any sense to run `net group my_gpo`.

Comment: I just noticed this is a post from TEN YEARS AGO... WTF is it doing on the home page?!?

Answer (score 0):

The greyed out Edit button may be caused by rights issue, make sure that you have the correct permissions to edit the GPO.

To see the users who'll be affected by this GPO, check the "security filetering" groups. the users in that group should be affected by your GPO (provided the're in the correct linked OU)

Comment: To follow up on @Florent's comment, I have this issue all the freakin' time with Windows 7 RSAT GPMC implementation.  The functional level of the domain is irrelevant; the GPMC, when looking at *linked* GPOs, has an issue.  This might be because our GPO's cross a domain trust, but every link GPO I try to "edit" from its linked location fails with an access denied error.  I have to open it from its original container as far as the GPMC GUI is concerned. Anyone else have this issue?  It worked before with GPMC in XP.

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear to me what you're asking but in the GPMC you can select the GPO in the left pane and see where it's linked on the Scope tab in the right pane and see what security filtering is being applied to the GPO. Based on that information you can deduce which users will have this policy applied based on their location in your AD structure and what security groups they're members of (are they in the Site, Domain, or OU where the GPO is linked and are they in a group that is being used to filter the GPO).